# Http Get Request in windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

Iam new to windows phone 8.1 app developement.i got stuck in getting response from API using httpclient get request..can anybody tell the best way to perform the get request from server in windows phone 8.1..thanks in advance

Comment: HttpClient client = new HttpClient();           client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.TryParseAdd("application/json");
string Responsestring = await client.GetStringAsync(new Uri("my link"));

Comment: this is my http get request im not getting any result

Comment: I would first check ID_CAP in your manifest to make sure you have the ability to for networking.

Comment: Im using the VS2015 vwersion and i enabled Internet(Client&server)capability in the manifestfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope the below helps

```
try{

 var client = new HttpClient();


    var uri = new Uri("your URI"); 

    //Call. Get response by Async
    var Response = await client.GetAsync(uri);

    //Result & Code
    var statusCode = Response.StatusCode;

    //If Response is not Http 200 
    //then EnsureSuccessStatusCode will throw an exception
    Response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    //Read the content of the response.
    //In here expected response is a string.
    //Accroding to Response you can change the Reading method.
    //like ReadAsStreamAsync etc..
    var ResponseText = await Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}

catch(Exception ex)
{
    //...
}
```